# Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Person cannot be cast to Person

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am testing spark application on docker all-spark-notebook, the Scala code is:

```
val p = spark.sparkContext.textFile ("../Data/person.txt")
val pmap = p.map ( _.split (","))
pmap.collect()
```

the output is:
`Array(Array(Barack, Obama, 53), Array(George, Bush, 68), Array(Bill, Clinton, 68))`

```
case class Person (first_name:String,last_name: String,age:Int)
val personRDD = pmap.map ( p => Person (p(0), p(1), p(2).toInt))
val personDF = personRDD.toDF
personDF.collect()
```

the error messages is above:

```
Name: org.apache.spark.SparkException
Message: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 12.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 12.0 (TID 17, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: $line145.$read$$iw$$iw$Person cannot be cast to $line145.$read$$iw$$iw$Person
    ................
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Person cannot be cast to Person
```

In fact, I tried to run this code with spark-shell, this code correctly run. I speculated that the above error message was related to docker environment, but not itself of the code. 
In addition,I tried to show personRDD, with：

```
personRDD.collect
```

I got the error message:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkDriverExecutionException: Execution error
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1186)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1711)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1354)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1327)
  ... 37 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: [LPerson;
  at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.array_update(ScalaRunTime.scala:90)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:2043)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:2043)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.JobWaiter.taskSucceeded(JobWaiter.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1711)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

I couldn't find out the reason why this problem produced. Could somebody give me some clues. Thanks.

Comment: How about you apply the case class over the txt file directly using SparkSQL?

Comment: Your code runs perfectly in mine :) may be you are doing some nasty stuffs somewhere else in the code. Did you put the case class outside the executing code?

Comment: I used the old code to test docker environment, which correctly run in the spark-shell, but not now.

Comment: try changing the name of the case class from `Person` to `Persons` and use in the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As cricket_007 has suggested in his comment to use `sqlContext`, you should go with `sparkSQL`.

Given input data file with `header` as

```
first_name,last_name,age
Barack,Obama,53
George,Bush,68
Bill,Clinton,68
```

You can do following

```
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .load("../Data/person.txt")
```

to get `dataframe` as

```
+----------+---------+---+
|first_name|last_name|age|
+----------+---------+---+
|Barack    |Obama    |53 |
|George    |Bush     |68 |
|Bill      |Clinton  |68 |
+----------+---------+---+
```

`schema` is generated as

```
root
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: string (nullable = true
```

You can define a `schema` and apply the `schema` as

```
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("first_name", StringType, true), StructField("last_name", StringType, true), StructField("age", IntegerType, true)))

val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .schema(schema)
  .load("/home/anahcolus/IdeaProjects/scalaTest/src/test/resources/t1.csv")
```

You should have `schema` as

```
root
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
```

If you don't have `header` in you file then you can remove the `header option`